# How frequently do aircraft get struck by lightning?

Tags: weather, lightning

We have several questions here about what happens to an aircraft when it gets struck by lightning (e.g. [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/888/65)), and at least one answer from a former pilot who knows he was struck once and thinks he was struck other times. **How frequently do aircraft get struck by lightning?**

Additional commentary on *how do you know you've been struck* would be appreciated, but I'll make that a separate question if it's more appropriate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lightning strikes airplanes [commonly](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-happens-when-lightni/), and for modern airplanes, it is not a big deal. Although, to put a definite number is not realistic, as it is not analogues to how many miles a car runs with a full tank.

On average, [it is estimated](http://flightsafety.org/aerosafety-world-magazine/june-2010/when-lightning-strikes) that lightning strikes an airplane **once every 1000 hours of flight time**.

Although, [as mentioned](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/2012_q4/4/):

> The frequency of lightning strikes that an airplane experiences is
>   affected by several factors, including the geographic area where the
>   airplane operates and how often the airplane passes through takeoff
>   and landing altitudes, which is where lightning activity is most
>   prevalent.

Comment: Every 1000 hours of what? Somewhere in the world, a plane is struck every 1000 hours? Each plane is struck every 1000 hours? Each plane is struck every 1000 hours of flight time?

Answer (score 21):

> It is estimated that on average, each airplane in the U.S. commercial fleet is struck lightly by lightning more than once each year.

*Edward J. Rupke, via [Scientific American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-happens-when-lightni/).*

> The Federal Aviation Administration estimates that on average, lightning hits each airliner in U.S. service once a year.

*[Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/capital-weather-gang/wp/2014/08/27/why-is-an-airplane-safe-from-lighting-strikes/)*

It looks like commercial airliners get struck about once a year. I was also able to find an [FAA source](http://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/transport/Cert_Update/Edition21-30/media/Edition23.pdf), but it doesn't look like it's the original source.